# Как в python+selenium webdriver открыть новую вкладку в уже открытом браузере?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет! Есть потребность: пройти авторизацию вручную на сайте, а уже через webdriver открыть новую вкладку в этом же браузере и продолжить работу с сайтом уже авторизованным. гугл не дал ответа, есть такая возможность?
По коду

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.ru/")
```

открывается хром в новой сессии, не авторизованный на нужном сайте (google.ru)

Comment: Так вроде нельзя, вам нужно придумать алгоритм авторизации именно через selenium+webdriver

Comment: вместо того чтобы пытаться подключиться к уже запущенному браузеру, можно существующий профиль использовать ([Profile path на  `chrome://version/`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31062789/4279)) или явно заходить.

Comment: @danilshik авторизация через вебдрайвер не проблема, но открытие новой вкладки в существующем браузере упростило бы саму работу скрипта

Comment: @jfs сейчас попробую, если буду использовать данные своего профиля, то и куки он тоже подхватит?

Comment: получилось по существующему профилю, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[В, соответствии, с ответом,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063104/5909792) нужно передавать аргумент `user-data-dir`, в котором будет путь до папки с профилем.

Путь до папки профиля, можно узнать из вкладки с адресом `chrome://version/`

```
from selenium import webdriver

FILE_NAME_PROFILE = r'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + FILE_NAME_PROFILE)

w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: путь нужно указывать без Default, с ним не работает. вот так: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data